# Maximum of an absolute value complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, absolute-value

I'm working my way through Marsden's Basic Complex Analysis book and I can't solve this problem. It's problem 23 of section 1.2 if that helps.

Let $a$ be a complex number, find the maximum of $|z^n+a|$ for those $z$ with $|z|\leq1$.

Comment: Hint: the maximum is achieved when $|z|=1$.

Comment: Is $n\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$?

Comment: @LordSoth The problem itself doesn't say but from the book I think $n$ is any natural number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** By the triangle inequality, $|z^n + a | \leq |z^n| + |a| =  1+ |a|$.

Can equality hold? If so, when does it hold?

Comment: OK, let me see if I got it, for equality to hold it must mean $z^n=\lambda a$ for some real $\lambda$. Also, we need $|z|=1$ which means $\lambda=1/|a|$. This means $z$ is an $n-$th root of $a/|a|$.